# Project Euler problem #19: counting months that began on Sundays

Tags: java, programming-challenge, datetime

> You are given the following information, but you may prefer to do some
>   research for yourself.
>
> - 1 Jan 1900 was a Monday.
> - Thirty days has September,
>     April, June and November.
> - All the rest have thirty-one,
>     Saving February alone,
>     Which has twenty-eight, rain or shine.
> - And on leap years, twenty-nine.
> - A leap year occurs on any year evenly divisible by 4, but not on a century unless it is divisible by 400.
>
> How many Sundays fell on the first of the month during the twentieth
>   century (1 Jan 1901 to 31 Dec 2000)?

```
public static void problem_19() {            
        int day = 4; // Lets number the days of week from 1:7 && SaturDay is the first day;;; note : 1 jan 1901 was Tue day
        int sundays = 0;
        for(int year = 1901; year <= 2000; year++) 
            for(int mon = 1; mon <= 12; mon++) {
                day += days(mon, year);
                if(day%7 == 1)
                    sundays++;
            }
        System.out.println(sundays);
    }
    public static int days(int num, int year) {
        int res = 0;
        int feb = 28;
        if(isLeapYear(year))
            feb = 29;
        switch(num) {
            case 1 : res = 31; break;
            case 2 : res = feb; break;
            case 3 : res = 31; break;
            case 4 : res = 30; break;
            case 5 : res = 31; break;
            case 6 : res = 30; break;
            case 7 : res = 31; break;
            case 8 : res = 31; break;
            case 9 : res = 30; break;
            case 10 : res = 31; break;
            case 11 : res = 30; break;
            case 12 : res = 31; break;
        }
        return res;
    }
    public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
        if(year%4 == 0) 
            if(year%100 == 0) {
                if(year%400 == 0)
                    return true;
            } else
                return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
>         int day = 4; // Lets number the days of week from 1:7 && Sunday is the first day;;; note : 1 jan 1901 was Tue day
> ```

The comment gets lost on the right edge of this narrow screen.

The position of the comment implies that it is specific to the variable `day`, but that's not true of the first sentence.

For working with `%` it would be less confusing to use 0 to 6 rather than 1 to 7.

Given that `day = 4`, why does the comment tell us that `1 jan 1901 was Tue day`? What does `day` represent here? If it's 1900-12-01 then the comment should talk about that date. In general, `day` is not a self-explanatory name.

---

> ```
>             for(int mon = 1; mon <= 12; mon++) {
> ```

`mon` for Monday? Again, not the most helpful name.

---

> ```
>                 day += days(mon, year);
>                 if(day%7 == 1)
>                     sundays++;
> ```

Is overflow of `day` a risk?

---

> ```
>     public static int days(int num, int year) {
>         int res = 0;
>         int feb = 28;
>         if(isLeapYear(year))
>             feb = 29;
>         switch(num) {
>             case 1 : res = 31; break;
>             case 2 : res = feb; break;
>             ...
>             case 12 : res = 31; break;
>         }
>         return res;
>     }
> ```

`num`? That's *completely* uninformative. I know it's a number because I can see that its type is `int`.

Early returns would make this shorter and more obviously correct:

```
        switch (month) {
            case 1 : return 31;
            case 2 : return isLeapYear(year) ? 29 : 28;
            ...
```

It's bad practice to have a `switch` without a `default`, even if the only thing the `default` does is `throw new Exception("This should be unreachable code")`.

One option would be to group the cases according to a well-known rhyme, and pull the sanity checking out of the `switch`:

```
        if (month < 1 || month > 12) throw new IllegalArgumentException("month");

        switch (month) {
            // 30 days have September, April, June and November...
            case 9:
            case 4:
            case 6:
            case 11:
                return 30;

            // ... All the rest have 31 ...
            default:
                return 31;

            // ... except for February alone.
            case 2:
                return isLeapYear(year) ? 29 : 28;
        }
```

---

> ```
>     public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
>         if(year%4 == 0) 
>             if(year%100 == 0) {
>                 if(year%400 == 0)
>                     return true;
>             } else
>                 return true;
>         return false;
>     }
> ```

Simplifying from the inside out, and putting in the necessary `{}` to be sure that the code does what we expect, we get:

```
    public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
        if (year % 4 == 0) {
            if (year % 100 == 0) {
                return year % 400 == 0;
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

```
    public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
        if (year % 4 == 0) {
            return y % 100 > 0 || year % 400 == 0;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

```
    public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
        return year % 4 == 0 && (y % 100 > 0 || year % 400 == 0);
    }
```

```
    public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
        return (year % 4 == 0 && y % 100 > 0) || year % 400 == 0;
    }
```

Of course, given that we're only interested in years 1901 to 2000, this could be simplified further.

Answer (score 0):

Fairly simple code.  On thing that caught my eye was the `isLeapYear` method.  I think the logic would be easier to understand by keeping it in one line:

```
if((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0){
     return true;
}
```